# Python send email behind a proxy server

Tags: python, proxy

I want to send an email using python script via hotmail smtp but I'm connected to a proxy server.

There is my code , it works when it's connected directely to internet but wen it's connected to a proxy server he doesn't work.

```
import smtplib

smtpserver = 'smtp.live.com'
AUTHREQUIRED = 1 
smtpuser = 'example@hotmail.fr'  
smtppass = 'mypassword'  

RECIPIENTS = 'mailto@gmail.com'
SENDER = 'example@hotmail.fr'
mssg = "test message"
s = mssg   

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver,587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls() 
server.ehlo()
server.login(smtpuser,smtppass)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(SENDER, [RECIPIENTS], s)
server.quit()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is: how can I edit script to send email through proxy

Comment: That depends. What sort of proxy is it? What services does it provide? How is it configured?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "*he doesn't work*"? Does it hang? Does it send the wrong email? Does it produce an error message? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Itried the given code in Answer 1 but I got this error msg ===>> socks.HTTPError: (502, 'Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) p ort is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests. )')

Comment: Also, to configure proxy in my browser, I use an url to a .pac file

Answer (score 11):

You can accomplish this with a module called [SocksiPy](https://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/) or [PySocks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySocks), the currently maintained fork:

```
import smtplib
import socks

#socks.setdefaultproxy(TYPE, ADDR, PORT)
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.SOCKS5, 'proxy.proxy.com', 8080)
socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)

smtpserver = 'smtp.live.com'
AUTHREQUIRED = 1 
smtpuser = 'example@hotmail.fr'  
smtppass = 'mypassword'  

RECIPIENTS = 'mailto@gmail.com'
SENDER = 'example@hotmail.fr'
mssg = "test message"
s = mssg   

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver,587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls() 
server.ehlo()
server.login(smtpuser,smtppass)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(SENDER, [RECIPIENTS], s)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, please how can I install socks module in windows? I didn't find package

Comment: @ImiiIik go to the link above, download the module, extract it to a folder and then from a command line run `python setup.py install`

Comment: I tried your code but I got this error message ==>

socks.HTTPError: (502, 'Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) p
ort is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this
 port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )')

Comment: I changed the type of proxy to "socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5" but nothing is happening and the script remains started

Comment: @ImiiIik What sort of proxy are you trying to use?  Is it HTTP or SOCKS5? What port is it on?

Comment: I Don't know exactly what sort of proxy, because I'm using a .pac file and in this file the used port for all addresses is 8080.

Comment: Did you try both `PROXY_TYPE_HTTP` and `PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5`? Are you sure you have the right proxy address?  Does it require authentication?

Comment: Yes I tried PROXY_TYPE_HTTP and the error msg is "socks.HTTPError: (502, 'Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) p
ort is not allowed. ISA Server.." and when I tried PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 or 4 nothing is happening and the script remains started

Answer (score 2):

To install socks module python.

```
sudo apt-get install python-socksipy
```

OR

You can also install using pip

```
pip install PySocks
```

Answer (score 2):

if your proxy is a **http proxy** you should use:

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.HTTP, 'proxy.proxy.com', 8080)
```

instead of `socks.SOCKS5`

Comment: This won't work if the HTTP proxy is not a CONNECT tunnel proxy.