# Errno 10060 A connection attempt failed

Tags: python, django, email, proxy

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'yogi'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '###'
DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM = 'yogi@gmail.com'
```

above are the settings for django core mail module. I am using its send_mail to send mails to users. When i try to build the program with the gmail smtp it throws the following error

> 'Errno 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party
>   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'.

I am doing this in my company and so it has proxy settings. I have given the proxy credentials in .condarc settings file. But still the connection timeout error. Do i need to set the proxy settings somewhere else or let me know where i am going wrong. ?

Comment: I would try to use another smtp server in order to see if the problem comes from gmail or your setup. Also a firewall (or even anti-virus) could block any smtp connection.

Comment: yes and when i try the same in my home it works completely fine.

Comment: thats obviously because your home location does not have any restrictions on outgoing SMTP while your office clearly does. Did specifying a proxy as suggested work for you? Of course it still wouldn't work if your proxy does not allow the use of google smtp servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know  django does not detect any SMTP proxy settings from anaconda configuration files. You can overcome this by manually building a connection.

Notice that [send_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/core/mail/#send_mail) , has an option parameter for a connection. You get one by calling [mail.get_connection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#email-backends) now you need to wrap it around sockspi

see [Python smtplib proxy support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239797/python-smtplib-proxy-support) and [Python send email behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830104/python-send-email-behind-a-proxy-server) for further details.