# python smtp proxy less

Tags: python, python-2.7

where is problem ? i want check server with proxy list but the code errors out:

```py
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
```

If i exclude the proxy key-word argument, it is working fine.

```
import  os, sys, smtplib
with open('proxy.txt') as urls:
    for line in urls:
        proxies=line.rstrip()
        file = open('sever.txt', 'r') # contains <server>:<user>:<pass>:<port>

        for line in file.readlines():
            list1 = line.split(':')

            try:
                server=smtplib.SMTP(list1[0]+':'+list1[3], proxies={"https":proxies})
                server.starttls()
                server.login(list1[1],list1[2])
                server.quit()
                with open ("valid.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write(str (list1[0]+":"+list1[1]))

            except Exception as e:
                print e
```

Comment: inside sever.txt server:user:pass:port

Comment: Does it throw an exception? If so, what is the exception (please add those details to the post itself)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, is this the standard `smtlib` library? If so, in their official documentation i don't see a `proxies` parameter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Comment: @Karan done you can see

Comment: responded. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the error message and it is now clear what is happening - `proxies` is not a valid parameter to the `smtplib`. Hence you get the `__init__()` error meaning it cannot initialize the Object with the given parameters.

If you wish to send emails through a proxy, I recommend reading through [Python smtplib proxy support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239797/python-smtplib-proxy-support)

using `socks` or any other python socket config package, you can set proxy settings before instantiating the SMTP client.

from [Python send email behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830104/python-send-email-behind-a-proxy-server):

```
#socks.setdefaultproxy(TYPE, ADDR, PORT)
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.SOCKS5, 'proxy.proxy.com', 8080)
socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)
```

Comment: how can i use proxy list ? and use random pick proxy ?

Comment: a simple, naive way to do this is: in your `for` loop, in each iteration, you can run the two `socks` methods i have above and keep re-wrapping your smtlib module on a new proxy in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

now i have problem there
my proxy list 2 line
server list 10 line
after 2 request code stopped :(

```
import  os, sys, smtplib
import socks
with open('proxy.txt') as urls:
    for line in urls:
        proxies=line.rstrip()
        try:
            socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.HTTP, proxies, 8080)
            socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)
            file = open('server.txt', 'r')
            for line in file.readlines():
                list1 = line.split(':')

            
            server=smtplib.SMTP(list1[0]+':'+list1[3])
            server.starttls()
            server.login(list1[1],list1[2])
            server.quit()
            print "valid   "+proxies+"   "+list1[1]
            with open ("valid.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(str (list1[0]+":"+list1[1])+'\n')

        except:
            print "bad   "+proxies+"   "+list1[1]
```

Comment: what do you mean stopped? Is there an exception being thrown? (don't swallow your exceptions. you should at least be doing this: `except Exception as e: print(e)`